# T-SQL change column names in Pivot table

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, pivot-table

I am trying to rename the column names of this PIVOT. As of right now, the column names are the Ids, I would like to have the Title (instead of the Id) from the GlobalTagging table.

I tried to save the title in a variable, then use it as the alias. For each title it's giving me an error "Invalid column name 'Abbinden'". Please help!

```
DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnId AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ActualColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @ColumnId = COALESCE(@ColumnId + ', ', '') + QUOTENAME(Id)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Id FROM GlobalTagging) AS Ids

SELECT @ActualColumnName = COALESCE(@ActualColumnName + ', ', '') + QUOTENAME(Title)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Title FROM GlobalTagging) AS Titles

SET @DynamicPivotQuery = 
   N'SELECT isnull(' + @ColumnId + ',0) AS ' + @ActualColumnName + '
   FROM (
       SELECT Video.Title, Video.Id AS Video_ID, Video.Id ,TI.GlobalTaggingId
       FROM Video left outer join TaggedItems TI on TI.ItemId = Video.Id
   ) AS SourceTable

   PIVOT (
       Count(Id)
       FOR GlobalTaggingId IN (' + @ColumnId + N')
   ) AS PivotTable'

EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery
```

Comment: FYI, using the syntax `SELECT @Variable = @Variable + ... FROM` is a [documented antipattern](//docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/select-local-variable-transact-sql#c-antipattern-use-of-recursive-variable-assignment) and should be avoided; it relies on the data engine processing your in a row by row order, which there is *no* guarantee of. Instead use string aggregation to achieve the same results. In recent versions of SQL Server that would be by using `STRING_AGG`, however, in older versions you'll need to use `FOR XML PATH` (and `STUFF`) to achieve the same results.

Comment: Honestly, this type of task is best left to your presentation layer. If you are "new to SQL" as you suggest then this isn't a path you should be going down yet; dynamic SQL *requires* understanding of what it does and how it works, as well as an understand of the query it's executing. Have your application transform the rows to columns; that's normally the best place for it anyway.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @ThomA! Would there be another approach to solve the issue as the one I attempted?

Comment: I would, personally, build a conditional aggregation query (instead of `PIVOT`) as it's easier to control and do stuff™ with, and (like mentioned above) get rid of the self-referencing variable.

Comment: Where is this dataset used? In an application or a report? Or is it dumped to excel for some mystery downstream purpose?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid it will be dumped to Excel!

Comment: If you're dumping it into Excel, why not just use the transpose columns feature of it? Or actually create a pivot table in the worksheet. You're definitely doing this in the *wrong* place.

Comment: Agreed. SQL is really not designed for dynamic column names, and Excel can do a Pivot pretty easily.

Comment: Also your query doesn't make a huge amount of sense. If you wrote this as a manula `GROUP BY` what would the grouping columns be?

Comment: Probably you need quotes around the titles, so your stuff looks like Column In ('Title', 'Title2'). since you didn't provide any sample data, it's hard to help you

Comment: Agreed - just dump the flat data into excel and use a pivot table rather than building complicated T-SQL stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you can just use a manual `PIVOT` query using conditional aggregation. This is probably the best way to do a pivot anyway as it's much more flexible.

```sql
DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @Columns AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @Columns = STRING_AGG(
  QUOTENAME(Title) + ' = COUNT(CASE WHEN GlobalTaggingId = ' + QUOTENAME(Id, '''') + ' THEN 1 END)',
  ',
  ')
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT Id, Title
    FROM GlobalTagging
) AS Ids;

SET @DynamicPivotQuery = 
   N'
SELECT
   v.Title,
  ' + @Columns + '
FROM Video v
LEFT JOIN TaggedItems TI ON TI.ItemId = v.Id
GROUP BY
  v.Id,
  v.Title;
'

EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery
```

Comment: that is exactly what I was looking for, works perfectly, thank you so much!!
In my case I had to convert the result of string_agg explicitly to NVARCHAR to make it work.